# mssql string split and update columns

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 columns - first one column A contains strings "abc/def" and second column B is empty. I would like to split strings and update columns with following results:

first column A: abc
second column B: def

For all column A entries.

Comment: I recommend that you read about basic SQL string manipulation functions and basic update statement. There are also few examples on SO.

Comment: You can find many examples about it. Please google it and you wil find many things.

Answer (score 2):

Using  `charindex()` to find the location of the delimiter, `left()` to get the left part, and `stuff()` to get the remaining part:

```
update t
set a = left(a, charindex('/',a+'/')-1)
  , b = stuff(a, 1,charindex('/',a+'/'),'')
;

select * from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WZFPH72760

returns:

```
+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |
+-----+-----+
| abc | def |
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select SUBSTRING('abc/def', 0, CHARINDEX('/','abc/def'))
select SUBSTRING('abc/def', CHARINDEX('/','abc/def')+1, len('abc/def'))
```

The first one for column A and the second one for column B

UPDATED with your update:

```
update myTable set ColumnA = SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 0, CHARINDEX('/',ColumnA)), ColumnB= SUBSTRING(ColumnA, CHARINDEX('/',ColumnA)+1, len(ColumnA))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "SUBSTRING"...

```
   update <table> set 
       columnB = (select SUBSTRING(columnA, CHARINDEX('/',columnA)+1, len(columnA)) from <table>),
       columnA = (select SUBSTRING(columnA, 0, CHARINDEX('/',columnA)) from <table>);
```

or look this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) for use STRING_SPLIT transact-Sql..

Hope this help!